# Passing Dictionary from controller to Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a view model like this:

```
public class weightdata
{
    ...some properties
    public string weights;
}
```

Then, I have in the controller:

```
weightdata details = new weightdata();
Dictionary<string,float> dict = new Dictionary<string,float>();
//do something to fill the dictionary with values
var ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
details.weights = ser.Serialize(dict);
return View(details);
```

Then in the view:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var dict = @{Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string,float>>(Model.Weights));}
 </script>
```

But the rendering of the page is:
    var dict = (it's blank)

How can I get this dictionary of values into where it can be used by javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Your property is already serialized, meaning it's already JSON. You don't want to deserialize it on the view, just write it out directly:

```
var dict = @Html.Raw(Model.Weights);
```

The other alternative is to make your property a `Dictionary<string, float>` instead of a string, then you would serialize it on the view:

```
 var dict = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Weights));
```

Something I just recently read about which may make your view a bit cleaner - you can actually dump the JSON into its own `script` tag with `type="application/json"`, and reference it in javascript. This may make your editor a little happier, since it's easier to separate the javascript from the C# code.

Something like:

```
<!-- assuming your Weights property is the serialized JSON string -->
<script id="some-json" type="application/json">
    @Model.Weights
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dict = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("some-json").innerHTML);
</script>
```

Just make sure you're targeting IE8+ or a real browser - if you need IE7 support, you'll need something like [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).